# AFHTTPSessionManager header

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am trying to set a default header for "Content-Type" by setting HTTPAdditionalHeaders. When I look at the request header, AFNetworking (v 2.0.3) changes it back. I also tried to set header by setValue:forHTTPHeaderField: on the requestSerializer, but no success. What I am missing?

**UPDATED**

```
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api"];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = @{@"Content-Type": @"multipart/form-data"};

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL sessionConfiguration:configuration];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [params setValue:@"some value" forKey:@"someKey"];

    [manager POST:@"search" parameters:params success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success");
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"error");
    }];
```

Comment: Are you using AFNetworking 2.0.3?

Comment: yes, AFNetworking 2.0.3

Comment: What does AFNeteworking change the content-type header back to?

Comment: @Aaron Brager, AFNetworking changes it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that AFNetworking set Content-Type automatically and you can not change it. To send data using Content-Type multipart/form-data:

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/api"];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:URL sessionConfiguration:configuration];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setValue:@"some value" forKey:@"someKey"];

[manager POST:@"search" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //If you need to send image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"my_image.jpg"];
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) name:@"Image" fileName:@"my_image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: What's the purpose of uploadTaskWithRequest:fromData:progress:completionHandler: so.. ? Just tracking progress ?

Comment: @kl94 I know that was an an old question, but the purpose of `uploadTaskWithRequest` is for creating a `NSURLSessionUploadTask` (which can be used in a background session, whereas this cannot). But this creates multipart request, which `uploadTaskWithRequest` does not.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking comes with a `AFJSONRequestSerializer` and `AFJSONResponseSerializer`:

```
[manager setRequestSerializer:[[AFJSONRequestSerializer alloc] init]];
[manager setResponseSerializer:[[AFJSONResponseSerializer alloc] init]];
```

Comment: I need to set different "Content-Type", not json.  "application/json" is just an example.

Comment: what are you setting it to? You've chosen 'application/json' in your question which also happens to be a default so I'm assuming you're hitting some race condition.

Comment: @timpone Sorry, maybe my question is misleading. I am trying to set "multipart/form-data"

Comment: y, you should update question then; probably don't want to be using AFJSONRequestSerializer

Comment: Why downvote this answer if your question isn't even correct?! The answer given is based on your original question which pertained to `application/json` with no mention of `multipart/form-data`.

Answer (score 1):

In the `AFURLRequestSerialization.m` file you can find the following property:

```
@property (readwrite, nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *mutableHTTPRequestHeaders;
```

Now you can subclass `AFHTTPRequestSerializer` (or `AFJSONRequestSerializer`) and add your desired HTTP headers to that mutable dictionary (don't forget to import the `AFURLRequestSerialization.m` file in your request serializer .m file).

Then you just set the `requestSerializer` property of your `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass to a new object of your new request serializer class (e.g. in the `init` method) and you're done. All requests with your session manager should include your HTTP headers then.