# AFHTTPSessionManager add body to POST

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking-2

I need too make a post request to my server.

With **AFHTTPRequestOperation** is very simple just use:

```
[request setHTTPBody: [requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

However i can't find any example how use the same approach using the **AFHTTPSessionManager**.

Using the method:

```
[self POST:@"extraLink" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {

}];
```

How i add the the body to the "AFMultipartFormData"?

Thanks in advace

Comment: example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20686179/afhttpsessionmanager-header

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As taken from the AFNetworking [home page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking), to create a `multipart/form-data` request, you call `appendPartWithFileURL`:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

But `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` is deprecated. So, instead, use `AFHTTPSessionManager`, for which the syntax of `POST` with the `constructingBodyWithBlock` is very similar:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"file://path/to/image.png"];
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:filePath name:@"image" error:nil];
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to post a request of the form `foo=bar&key=value&...` (i.e. an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request), you would do something like:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar", @"key": @"value"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: There is another option to attach the data to the body? I have a string with a list "key=value&key=value&..." which is my body request. Do you know any way to add a plain string? @Rob

Comment: That `key=value&key=value&...` format is an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type request (whereas the above creates a `multipart/form-data` request). If you need the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, use the other rendition of `POST` without the `constructingBodyWithBlock` parameter.

Comment: sorry @Rob but I did not understand you fully. Can you give me an example of how to add the body using the other POST method? Thanks

Comment: just to confirm @Rob, i still need to convert my object "NSString" to a NSDictionary struture? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you probably want to that (because AFNetworking will do the necessary percent-escaping that one needs to do for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests). I guess you could create the percent-escaped body of the request yourself and then build the request yourself, but that's a lot more work.

Comment: i get a warning 'Post:parameters:success:failure' is depreciated when i use the alternative example

Comment: @Edwin - Yep, it now has rendition with `progress` block. See revised answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try this other way.

I'm converting my image in data format which is `imageData`.

```
NSData *imageData=nil;
imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimageName"],0.2);
NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary new];
[dict setObject:@"user1" forKey:@"param_name1"];
[dict setObject:@"User2" forKey:@"param_name2"];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];

[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                              serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[manager POST:@"API NAME" parameters:dict constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData>  _Nonnull formData) {

 if(imageData)
 {
     [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData  name:@"param_name" fileName:@"filename.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
 }
 } progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress)
 {
     NSLog(@"%@",uploadProgress);
 } success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
     NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

 } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
     NSLog(@"%@",error);

 }];
```