# How to add raw body in AFHTTPSessionManager request?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

[image: Postman Screen]
I want To add Raw body in my AFHTTPSessionManager request

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26298593/afhttpsessionmanager-add-body-to-post

Answer (score -1):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager;

  manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
 manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
 [manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:10.0];
[manager POST:strRequestUrl parameters:dictParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
        {
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 }];
```